# Angular - Display server error in component

Tags: javascript, html, angular, forms

I'm currently working on a register page and therefore, I need to post my data to the server. The client-side validation and server-validation works. I know I can handle the client-side errors like `*ngIf="(emailAddress.errors?.required || emailAddress.errors?.email) && emailAddress.touched"`. But how to handle the server-side errors?

In my service, if an error occurs, I simply give it into the component by `return throwError(error);`
But how can I know to display the specific error in my component if for example there is already someone with this email address? And how do distinguish between email/password validation errors server side?

Comment: The server would need to return the details of the error, and then your front end would need to respond to those details

Comment: Like giving an 'area' tag to the error and then displaying the error at the right 'area' in the template? @OliverRadini

Comment: potentially, how you'd like to display it is up to you; basically you need to make the call to the server, and the server needs to return an error. The front end can then respond to that in any way you like

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the complexity and modules you have.

If you use any kind of state management library such as ngrx or ngxs, I suggest you do as follow:

- Define State with a property 'error' which keeps track of the latest server-error.
- Api call executed via actions and error is caught and stored to state also via actions. (Do whatever error mapping before saving the error to your State)
- Use selectors for component to receive error stream from State.

If you don't have any state management library, you can create a BehaviorSubject within singleton service, and use it to publish server-error as soon as you got into any catchError context.

Answer (score 0):

This way you can write your own **http interceptor** and have your response inside your component. Also in your component you know your http response is success or error.
You can implement other Http calls(`GET`, `PUT`, etc) and also handle your general errors in `handleError()` function.

app.module.ts

```
export class AppModule {
   constructor() {}

   imports: [
          HttpClientModule,
   ],
   providers: [
      {
          provide: Http,
          useFactory: httpFactory,
          deps: [HttpHandler]
      },
   ],
}

export function httpFactory(httpHandler: HttpHandler) {
    return new Http(httpHandler);
}
```

http.service.ts

```
export class Http extends HttpClient {
   constructor(handler: HttpHandler) {
      super(handler);
   }

   postCall(url: string, body, options?): Observable<any> {
      return super.post(url, body, options)
          .pipe(
             tap(response => { console.log(response) }),
             catchError(this.handleError(error)));
   }

  private handleError<T>(result?: T) {
     return (error: any): Observable<T> => {
        console.log(error);
        return of(result as T);
     };
  }
}
```

your.component.ts

```
export class YourComponent {
   constructor(private http: Http) {}

   this.http.postCall('URL', {}).subscribe(response => {
      if (response instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
          // Your Response is error
      } else {
         // Your Response is your desired result
      }
}
```